# Download Cypress For Linux

Tags: linux, browser, operating-systems, node.js, cypress

I'm trying to download cypress for Linux so I would be able to install it later so my cypress project would run there. In cypresses website, they say this link: [https://download.cypress.io][1] is "to download a specific Cypress version for a given platform". When I click it, it downloads the cypress version for the current os that is running the web browser.

Is there a way I could download cypress for any os (linux, windows, mac) and any version so I could upload it to an offline repo? I'm looking for download and not an istallation

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ask over here>>>>>https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply additional parameters to https://download.cypress.io:

> We currently have the following downloads available:
>
> - Windows 64-bit (?platform=win32&arch=x64)
> - Windows 32-bit (?platform=win32&arch=ia32, available since Cypress 3.3.0)
> - Linux 64-bit (?platform=linux)
> - macOS 64-bit (?platform=darwin)
>
> See https://download.cypress.io/desktop.json for all available platforms.

[source](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Download-URLs)